# Using a Hashmap to keep track of original count or not

Tags: java, android

I am scanning the `MediaStore` on app start. I iterate over it for audio tracks and store them. I also store other aspects like albums. I store the tracks in an `ArrayList` and that also goes for albums (different `ArrayList`) This works fine but I have started to consider the performance.

I want to keep track of tracks count, for each album, while scanning. So, I originally used a `HashMap` of album id -> tracks count. With each track I get during scanning, I check if the `HashMap` (associated with the album id) exists or not. I create it when it does not exist and update it with the count otherwise. Then, after the scanning, I would iterate over the albums `ArrayList` and update the entries with the information from `HashMap` by using the `HashMap` lookup.

I am starting to wonder if it is worth it to use `HashMap` here for performance. Will skipping the `HashMap` and looking up the album I want to update, using a for loop, then updating it, be better in performance?

Thanks.

Edit: since I cannot post the code because it is a large chunk, so I will simplify it. Original code:

```
private void scanTracks()
{
    HashMap<Long, Integer> albumHashMap= new HashMap<>();

    // Iterate over tracks in MediaStore Block Start

    // Get albumId.

    if (!albumHashMap.containsKey(albumId))
        albumHashMap.put(albumId, 1);
    else
        albumHashMap.put(albumId, albumHashMap.get(albumId) + 1);

    // Iterate over tracks in MediaStore Block End

    for(Album album : mAlbums)
    {
        album.setCount(albumHashMap.get(album.getId()));
    }
}
```

Here is the alternative implementation I am suggesting.

```
private void scanTracks()
{
    // Iterate over tracks in MediaStore Block Start

    // Get albumId.

    for (Album album : mAlbums)
    {
        if (album.getId() == albumId)
        {
            album.secCount(album.getCount()+1);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Iterate over tracks in MediaStore Block End
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your question, can you post a sample code for this? but for lookup concern always Maps are preferred.

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am scanning the MediaStore on app start. I iterate over it for audio tracks and store them. I also store other aspects like albums. I store the tracks in an ArrayList and that also goes for albums (different ArrayList) This works fine but I have started to consider the performance.

With this description, I understand that you have a list of all the tracks, which is not grouped by album. Then, you have another list of all the albums.

If that's the case, with the use of `HashMap`, the time complexity will be `O(n + m)`, where n and m is the count of tracks and albums, respectively. Haven't evaluated the performance of the other way, I can say that this is a sign of good performance.

Now, if you go through each album in the album list, and then iterate the tracks to count, the time complexity would be `O(m*n)`, which is far worse than the above `O(m + n)`.

So in recap, use `HashMap`.

Comment: did you get the chance to check my question edit out?

Comment: Hi @JohnAnderson, your updated question has confirmed my understanding of the problem. My answer stays valid still, as you can see in your alternative implementation, there is nested loop that cause the time complexity of `O(m*n)`. In your initial implementation, HashMap operation in general has time complexity of `O(1)`, thus the time complexity of the whole method is just `O(m+n)`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hung Thai. I appreciate it. If you got the time can you check my other question here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527248/using-hashmap-for-an-extra-paremeter-vs-using-split

Answer (score 1):

Clearly

```
1st approach

first loop goes for n times
second loop goes for m times (say)

Advantage: overall time complexity O(m+n)
Disadvantage: Additional space complexity O(n) (hashmap)

2nd Apporach

Outer loop goes for n times
    inner loop goes for m times

Advantage: No additional space complexity (no use for hashmap)
Disadvantage: overall time complexity O(m*n)
```

It is a trade off between time and space complexity, IMHO I would suggest 1st approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, Sabareesh Muralidharan. It is too bad I cannot select two answers here. I went with Hung's because it was the first one.

Comment: Cool...anyways I have tried answering to your follow up que. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527248/using-hashmap-for-an-extra-paremeter-vs-using-split/62527747#62527747. Hope that helps!!