# Using Hashmap for an extra paremeter vs using Split

Tags: java, android

I am iterating over tracks belonging to a genre in the `MediaStore`. I iterate over them and create a map of track id->genre id for later use by my scan tracks method. What I am doing is similar to the following:

```
private void scanGenres()
{
   // Iterate over genres block start.
      // Iterate over tracks by a genre start
         mTracksGenreHashMap.put(trackId, genreId);
      // Iterate over tracks by a genre start
   // Iterate over genres block end.
}
```

I realized that I also need to store the genre name not just the genre id for use by my tracks scanning method. I have two options. I can create a new `HashMap` of genre id to genre name. My other other is to put the genre name in the value of my `mTracksGenreHashMap` `HashMap`. First option:

```
private void scanGenres()
{
   // Iterate over genres block start.
      // Iterate over tracks by a genre start
         mTracksGenreHashMap.put(trackId, genreId);
         mGenreIdToNameHashMap.put(genreId, genreName);
      // Iterate over tracks by a genre start
   // Iterate over genres block end.
}
```

Second option:

```
private void scanGenres()
{
   // Iterate over genres block start.
      // Iterate over tracks by a genre start
         mTracksGenreHashMap.put(trackId, genreId + ";" + genreName);
      // Iterate over tracks by a genre start
   // Iterate over genres block end.
}
```

Then, on my scan tracks method:

```
private void scanTracks()
{
    // Iterate over tracks in MediaStore start
        // Get track Id.
        // First option.
        long genreId = mTracksGenreHashMap.get(trackId); 
        String genreName = mGenreIdToNameHashMap.get(genreId);

        // OR

        // Second option
        string[] genreIdName = mTracksGenreHashMap.get(trackId);
        string genreId = genreIdName[0];
        string genreName = genreIdName[1];
    // Iterate over tracks in MediaStore end
}
```

I want to know which solution would perform better. Keep in mind that on each of the methods, I loop over tracks. On the first one, I loop over the tracks within a genre. On `scanTracks()` I loop over all tracks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joni suggested it would be wiser to use A `Genre` as its own Object with Name and ID, but if you just wanted to select between your two approaches, I would suggest you to follow your first approach.

```
mTracksGenreHashMap.put(trackId, genreId);
mGenreIdToNameHashMap.put(genreId, genreName);
```

Where you'll have a specific functional use case for each of your hashmap and using the second apporach,

```
        long genreId = mTracksGenreHashMap.get(trackId); 
        String genreName = mGenreIdToNameHashMap.get(genreId);

        // OR

        // Second option
        string[] genreIdName = mTracksGenreHashMap.get(trackId);
        string genreId = genreIdName[0];
        string genreName = genreIdName[1];
```

I could see the `genreId` being a long value, initially while storing you have to combine `genreId` and `genreName` as a String and while fetching you have to do a Long cast operation from String which I feel are unnecessary.

Even if any change in any of the maps using `1st Approach` that operation would be atomic (means you'll either change map1 or map2) but using `2nd Approach` you have to fetch and update both the value as they are jus one whole String.

Hence, my suggestion would be to use `1st Approach`

//Happy learning!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like "genre" is a meaningful concept in its own right, so it should be represented as a *class* in your program, not as pieces of data striped across different data structures:

```
class Genre {
    public final String id;
    public final String name;
}

mTracksGenreHashMap.put(trackId, genreObject);
```

> "I want to know which solution would perform better"

The difference is too small to be meaningful in realistic use cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Would using a separate model like you suggested increase memory usage more than my solutions or affect performance at all? I am considering using the model, if they are all the same. I already have a model for Genre which I later fill with data. The reason I do not fill the Genre model on my `scaneGenre()` method is that I determine the count of tracks within `scanTracks()` method. I cannot determine the count on `scanGenre()` because I filter the tracks on `scanTracks()`

Comment: This is actually a followup question from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62511026/using-a-hashmap-to-keep-track-of-original-count-or-not

Comment: Do you expect to have millions of genres? If not, you're worrying about the wrong thing

Comment: It is not that, I am concerned because in my code above, in `scanGenre()`, each track id will be linked to a model/csv data. Some users may have 2k tracks on their phones. That is my main concern.

Comment: For 2k tracks you will need 2k links between track and genre. 1) **that's a small number** - focus on actual features that bring value to the user! 2) an object reference to a shared immutable genre object takes minimal space and is pretty convenient to work with